# is this a good place to DRY out code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, architecture

The owner of a site that I am working on has asked me to make the About Us page editable (by her, through a web interface).  In fact, there are 5 pages in total that she wants to make editable - About Us, Terms of Service, and so on.

In the old implementation, when these pages were static view files, I had all the URLs coded into `routes.rb`

```
scope :controller => :home do
  get :about
  get :terms
  # etc ...
end
```

Now that these different actions are fetching data from the DB (or wherever) it seems like the standard RESTful approach might be to make a `Pages` resource and consolidate all the views into a `show` action.

That doesn't feel quite right. Individual resources aren't usually hardwired into the site the way an About Us page is - the contents of the page might change, but the page itself isn't going anywhere, and there are links to it in the footer, in some of our emails, etc.

Specifically, factoring out the individual routes from the PagesController would raise the following problems:

- I couldn't used named route helpers like `about_path`
- The routes for permanent pages on the site would be stored in the database, which means that...
- maintenance would probably be a headache, since that is not the normal place to keep routes.

So currently I think that the best approach is to leave these URLs coded into `routes.rb`, and have separate controller actions, each of which would fetch its own page from the DB.

Can anyone share some insight?  How do you deal with data that's not totally static but still needs to be hard-wired into the site?

Comment: Will you allow them to include HTML tags with their submissions or just text?  How about linked images or other resources?

Comment: @Perry - We were going to use Markdown for the text.  So yes to HTML tags, no to images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to allow markdown, I like the idea of a Pages controller and model.  If your layout feels like all 5 pages should have a similar feel, then I'd go with one template that populates with the user generated content and appropriate navigation.

My choice would be to set the routes, make the views (including routing), and populate the views with the user generated markdown.

Without knowing more about your site, it's hard to say, but my preference is not to allow users to generate pages that reflect the site identity (About, terms, etc.) unless that's what they are paying for.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ended up doing.  I've got a Pages controller, and one `show` template that renders all the pages, but the routes for the pages are all listed individually in `routes.rb`, and there's no `create` action in the controller, so there's no way for users to add new pages.